# How do I get the tabcontrol effect with buttons and a frame

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm trying to get the same effect as a tab control where the button kinda merges into the frame seamlessly.

If we look at this one, we can see that there is nothing cutting off the "Red" button from the frame. It kinda just goes into the frame
[image]

To be more explicit, this is what I'm focusing on

[image]

And I wanted to accomplish the same effect with buttons and a frame but I'm not sure how to do it.
What's the proper way of accomplishing the same effect? Is there a style I should inherit from?

This is what I have

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel>
                <Button Height="50"/>
                <Button Height="50"/>
                <Button Height="50"/>
                <Button Height="50"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Frame/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: `RadioButton` would be an option, which has a checked state, applying a style to them with a `Trigger` for the case when checked, to get rid of the border

Comment: "Is there a style I should inherit from" - use TabControl and change Template of TabItem

Answer (score 0):

## Sample for your screenshot

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
                <TabItem Header="Header 1">
                    <Label Content="Text write here..." />
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Header 2" />
                <TabItem Header="Header 3" />
                <TabItem Header="Header 4" />
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```